# Horizontal CSS Funnel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I have been task to create a funnel like the following...

I have looked at some examples [here](http://pykcharts.com/) and [here](http://www.cssscript.com/creating-funnel-charts-using-svg-and-d3-js-d3-funnel/) 
and also found the following [link](http://bit.ly/1hfmQjz) but i cant get the funnel to lie on its side.
I am not even sure if i am looking at the right stuff.

Has anybody created something like this before.

[image]

***Updated***
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwt1qua3/5/) of what i have done so far

```
  <div class="container">

        <div style="float:left;width:200px;height:140px;background:#E34743"></div>
        <div class="arrow-right float-left"></div>


        <div class="trapezoid-second"></div>
        <div class="trapezoid-second-last"></div>
        <div class="trapezoid-last"></div>

        <div class='float-left' style="margin-top: -15px;">
            <div class="green-box"></div>
            <div class="green-box"></div>
            <div class="green-box"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest considering SVG for this rather than CSS. It should be perfectly possible to do this kind of thing in CSS, but SVG will probably be easier, and certainly more flexible if you need to make any changes later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So managed to create the funnel, i added the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnLj96pb/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="red-arrow">
        <div class="red-border">Brand Posts</div>
        <div class="red-border">Brand Posts</div>
        <div class="red-border">Brand Posts</div>
        <div class="red-border">Brand Posts</div>

    </div>
    <div class="arrow-right float-left" style="z-index:3;">

    </div>
    <div class="arrow-right float-left" style="border-left-color:#262626;margin-left: -15px;"></div>
    <div class="box one" style="position:relative;float:left">
        <div class="top-border"></div>
        <div class="box-content">

            <p class="white-header">24,719</p>
            <p class="white-small">Engaged Users</p>
            <p class="white-small">+483% W/W</p>

        </div>
        <div class="bottom-border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box two" style="position:relative;float:left">
        <div class="top-border"></div>
        <div class="box-content">

            <p class="white-header">16,719</p>
            <p class="white-small">Engagements + clicks</p>
            <p class="white-small">+483% W/W</p>

        </div>
        <div class="bottom-border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box three" style="position:relative;float:left">
        <div class="top-border"></div>
        <div class="box-content">

            <p class="white-header">24,719</p>
            <p class="white-small">Total Reach**</p>
            <p class="white-small">+483% W/W</p>

        </div>
        <div class="bottom-border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box four" style="position:relative;float:left">
        <div class="top-border"></div>
        <div class="box-content">

            <p class="white-header">2,869,966</p>
            <p class="white-small">Total impressions</p>
            <p class="white-small">+263% W/W</p>

        </div>
        <div class="bottom-border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='float-left' style="margin-top: -40px; padding-left: 5px;">
        <div class="green-box">

            <div class="green-box-content">
                <p class="large">2,441</p>
                <p class="small">Engagements (likes, Comments, Shares)</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="green-box">
            <div class="green-box-content">
                <p class="large">14k</p>
                <p class="small">clicks</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="green-box">
            <div class="green-box-content">
                <p class="large">815</p>
                <p class="small">New Page Likes</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #262626;
}

.box {
    margin: 0 1px;
}

.top-border {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 45px solid #5475B6;
    border-right: 150px solid #5475B6;
    border-bottom: 60px solid #5475B6;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}

.bottom-border {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 45px solid #5475B6;
    border-right: 150px solid #5475B6;
    border-top: 60px solid #5475B6;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

.box-content {
    background: #5475B6;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto 0;
    width: 149px;
    margin-top: -35px;
}

.box.one {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.box.two {
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.box.two .top-border {
    border-bottom-width: 70px;
}

.box.two .bottom-border {
    border-top-width: 70px;
}

.box.three {
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.box.three .top-border {
    border-bottom-width: 80px;
}

.box.three .bottom-border {
    border-top-width: 80px;
}

.box.four {
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.box.four .top-border {
    border-bottom-width: 90px;
}

.box.four .bottom-border {
    border-top-width: 90px;
}

h1,
select {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#funnel {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.green-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 66px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background: #70A444;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #E34743;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 70px solid transparent;
    border-right: 70px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #fff;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.white-header {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.white-small {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 25px;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.green-box-content {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.green-box-content > .large {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.green-box-content > .small {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.red-arrow {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #E34743;
}

.red-border {

    width: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 29px;
    display: inline-block;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The places you link to have JS libraries how to create *dynamic* funnels: the shape of the funnel depends on the content. With d3js (steep learning curve) you may be able to create a dynamic horizontal funnel.

However: your picture/ screenshot is not dynamic. It looks like the shape of the picture is always the same, and only the text is different.

It would be a lot easier to either:

- Create one big background picture and layout the texts on top of that. This is a quick & dirty solution. Not the right route if you want the picture to behave responsively.
- Recreate all entire shapes with css. May involve stitching different elements together. This would allow you to e.g. change background color of one part depending on the numbers.

You could look at: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ for more info on css shapes.

Comment: i guess those are valid options, i don't really have to use d3js it was just the examples that i got. I don't think the funnel will grow, assuming it does i don't want to re-create the background image if i go that route.

Comment: Plus one, because i used your method of created each section individually. My requirement has changed slightly but i managed to create it.